# How does the Memory and IO addresses treated differently in the endpoint device?

Tags: pci, pci-e

Let assume we have two PCIe endpoint devices A and B. A implements MMIO addresses and B implements IO address. How does these endpoints handles these addresses internally ? How it is decided that the endpoint should use MMIO or IO address or both ?  What difference it will make from a PCIe endpoint point of view ?
It just looks like address used to interact with the host.

Answer (score 0):

The device designer decides whether to implement IO space or MMIO space or both. (But I think the PCIe spec may have some requirements about implementing MMIO space.)

The two types of operations appear as different transaction types when they arrive at the device. It is up to the device to determine how to process them. It may not make any difference.

Memory write operations are posted, meaning no response from the device is required, while I/O writes are non-posted, so a response is required. Both memory and I/O reads are non-posted, of course. (https://paritycheck.wordpress.com/2008/01/13/pcie-posted-vs-non-posted-transactions)

There may also be differences in how the CPU handles them. For example, on x86, I/O instructions are serializing (and therefore slower).